# Problem with displaying Japanese text strings using JavaScript code in Pavlovia

Tags: javascript, utf-8, psychopy

I'm trying to translate text in a javascript file which has been created using English into Japanese. When I just change the string to Japanese characters using copy & paste, the text in Pavlovia is displayed as '?????'. From what I could gather from other posts this has something to do with the fact that Japanese characters are encoded in UTF-8, which is not the standard encoding used in my JavaScript file. I have tried saving the whole file with encoding UTF-8, but this seemingly cannot be read Pavlovia. So I assume I need some local UTF-8 encoding of the individual Japanese text bits.

Unfortunately I have zero JavaScript experience, so any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi @BiancaS, what you've asked isn't really a programming question and hence not really suitable for StackOverflow. I'd suggest you take this question to the dedicated PsychoPy/PsychoJS support forum at https://discourse.psychopy.org where the actual PsychoPy developers can be found. I'd suggest that you also provide them with an example file so they can see exactly where the issue lies.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I also posted on the psychopy discourse forum as I didn't really know whether the problem was caused by Psychopy/Pavlovia or internal to the javascript file that our task relies on. Initially I thought it was something relating to how javascript handles different character codes. However the issue seems to have resolved on its own now, as the translation is working fine and all japanese characters are displayed correctly - not sure why it didn't work initially.